# DataGrid how to get the value of the CurrentCell

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have to access the value that underlies the active cell of a DataGrid (The cell with the black border around it).

Luckily DataGrid has a lot of properties such as CurrentCell, CurrentItem SelectedCells SelectedItem and SelectedItems seeming to provide me with the data I want.

However I have not figured out how to access the cell in an easy way. I also have changed the …

```
SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

...properties but in the end I had to do something like this:

```
DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = dataGrid.CurrentCell;

if(null != cellInfo && cellInfo.IsValid)
{
    object[] array = cellInfo.Item as object[];
    if (null != array && cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex >= 0 && cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex < array.Length) 
    {
        object cellValue = array[cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex];
        if (null != cellValue) 
        {
            // Here we are
        }
    }
}
```

In my example, the row is built through an object-array containing various object-types. I'm aware that I could execute the binding on the cellInfo.Column (after a cast), however that is not the point. My question is, if I make something really wrong, because I cannot imaging that such a powerful piece of software as DataGrid is, can not provide me the desired value without doing such a lot of coding.

**What have I missed or is it really such complicated to get the current cells value.**

**UPDATE**

As Quartermeister explained in his very good answer, there is not a single property to access the cells value and this is has a meaningfull cause. besides, beware of using the DisplayIndex as I do in my example if you let the user rearrange the columns.

Comment: Why do you need to access the value directly? The datagrid is designed to work with databinding and mvvm pattern, which should avoid the need to access the ui class (data grid cell in your case) directly.

Comment: I don't see how MVVM can help me in this case? How can I bind the current cell to my view model (or which property I must bind to), so that my view model tracks the current cell without writing some code as I did above. I would be interested in such a solution because I dont like the way I did.

Comment: Please see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272910/fill-a-datagrid-with-data-that-lies-in-a-array
maybe you can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really is that complicated.  The problem is that a DataGridColumn isn't necessarily bound to a single value.  A [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(VS.95).aspx), for example, just has a DataTemplate.  The template may use multiple values from the row object or even no values at all, so there is no way to usefully return a single value for that cell.

You can be guaranteed to have a single value if the column is a [DataGridBoundColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn(VS.95).aspx) (such as a [DataGridTextColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn(v=VS.95).aspx)).  As you said, you can get the value by executing the Binding.  For example, you could do something like this (note that this won't work for a binding that uses ElementName or RelativeSource, but you probably won't use those in a DataGridBoundColumn):

```
var cellInfo = dataGrid.CurrentCell;
if (cellInfo != null)
{
    var column = cellInfo.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (column != null)
    {
        var element = new FrameworkElement() { DataContext = cellInfo.Item };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, FrameworkElement.TagProperty, column.Binding);
        var cellValue = element.Tag;
    }
}
```

Note that you probably don't want to use the DisplayIndex property, since that can be changed if the user manually drags the columns to reorder them.

Comment: +1 and Accept: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Now it makes sense to me. By the way, nice way to Execute the binding.

Comment: Wow 7 lines of code to get the current cell value and it returns NULL. Any idea who designed this poor excuse for a grid. I guess all the good programmers that Microsoft used to have went to Google or AWS.